# Is there a function which returns the filepath at the cursor?

Tags: vimrc, regular-expression, functions

I'm looking for a function(probably doesn't exist) which can return the filepath under the cursor. I know that there is a command/shortcut `gf` that helps me jump to that file if the file exists.

But I do wonder, is there a function so that I can simply get that filename/filepath without opening it? If not, that function might be very useful in some cases. Are there any elegant ways to implemente the function(use regex?)?

As far as I know, the only way seems using pattern matching. However, the regex and the matching logic seems a little complex(suppose there are multiple filenames in the line which the cursor locates at)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `expand(.)` with argument `'<cfile>'`:

```
expand({expr} [, {nosuf} [, {list}]])               *expand()*
        Expand wildcards and the following special keywords in {expr}.
        'wildignorecase' applies.
        ...
        When {expr} starts with '%', '#' or '<', the expansion is done
        like for the |cmdline-special| variables with their associated
        modifiers.  Here is a short overview:
        ...
            <cfile>     file name under the cursor
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much and sorry for my stupid question...

Comment: And I ever thought `expand('<cfile>')` only returns the path of the **current buffer**... I am wrong...